# Simple OpenGL image viewer in C

Tags: c, opengl, c11

I'm making an image viewer and before I continue development I want to make sure I haven't done anything bad. In particular, I was wondering if my error handling is sane.

Most of the code is OpenGL/glfw boilerplate, so far all that happens is the creation of an OpenGL context and then I use stb_image to load the image (in function "load_image") and then I gen/bind my textures/buffers respectively and finally render.

Error handling is fairly straightforward; a generic error function that prints what is passed to it and exits, wrapped in a macro that prints the specific file, line, and function where the error occurred.

**eternity.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include "eternity.h"
#include "error.h"
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STBI_FAILURE_USERMSG
#include "stb_image.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct argp_option options[] =
    {
        {0}
    };

    static const char* doc = "Eternity - your window to the good";
    struct argp argp = {options, parse_opt, "[FILE]", doc, 0, 0, 0};

    int arg_count = 1;
    argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arg_count);

    eternity_image image = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2};
    unsigned char *image_raw = load_image(argv[image.current_image], &image);

    if (!image_raw)
        DIE("stbi error: %s\n", stbi_failure_reason());

    uint8_t rv;
    if ((rv = initialize_glfw()))
        DIE("%s%" PRIu8 "\n", "initialize_glfw() failed with code ", rv);

    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);

    GLFWmonitor *primary = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();
    const GLFWvidmode *mode = glfwGetVideoMode(primary);
    const GLint screen_width = mode->width, screen_height = mode->height;

    GLFWwindow *window;
    if (!(window = glfwCreateWindow(
                    image.width < screen_width ? image.width : screen_width,
                    image.height < screen_height ? image.height : screen_height,
                    "Eternity",
                    NULL,
                    NULL)))
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        DIE("%s\n", "glfwCreateWindow failed");
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, glfw_key_callback);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        eternity_cleanup(window);
        DIE("%s\n", "glewInit() failed");
    }

    printf("OpenGL %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    GLshort vertices[] = {
        -1,  1, 0,
         1,  1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0,
         1, -1, 0
    };

    GLshort texcoords[] = {
         0,  0,
         1,  0,
         0,  1,
         1,  1
    };

    GLuint vertices_vbo = 0;
    setup_vbo(&vertices_vbo, vertices, 12 * sizeof(vertices));

    GLuint texcoords_vbo = 0;
    setup_vbo(&texcoords_vbo, texcoords, 8 * sizeof(texcoords));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_vbo);

    GLuint vao = 0;
    setup_vao(&vao);

    GLuint shader_program = 0;
    if (setup_shaders(&shader_program))
    {
        eternity_cleanup(window);
        DIE("%s\n", "shader compilation failed");
    }

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoords_vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_vbo);

    GLuint texture_id = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width, image.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_raw);
    stbi_image_free(image_raw);

    check_error();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shader_program);
        glBindVertexArray(vertices_vbo);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id);
    eternity_cleanup(window);
}

unsigned char* load_image(char *name, eternity_image *image)
{
    return stbi_load(name, &image->width, &image->height, &image->bpp, STBI_rgb_alpha);
}

void setup_vbo(GLuint *vbo, GLshort *vbo_array, GLuint size)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vbo_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void setup_vao(GLuint *vao)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(*vao);
}

uint8_t setup_shaders(GLuint *shader_program)
{
    const GLchar *vs_source =
        "#version 440\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec2 vt;"
        "out vec2 texcoord;"
        "void main() { gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);"
        "texcoord = vt; }",
               *fs_source =
        "#version 440\n"
        "out vec4 frag_color;"
        "in vec2 texcoord;"
        "uniform sampler2D texture;"
        "void main() { frag_color = texture2D(texture, texcoord); }";

    GLint compile_ok = GL_FALSE;

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
    if (compile_ok != GL_TRUE)
    {
        glDeleteShader(vs);
        return 1;
    }

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
    if (compile_ok != GL_TRUE)
    {
        glDeleteShader(fs);
        return 1;
    }

    *shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(*shader_program, fs);
    glAttachShader(*shader_program, vs);
    glLinkProgram(*shader_program);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return 0;
}

uint8_t initialize_glfw(void)
{
    int major = 0, minor = 0, rev = 0;

    glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
    printf("GLFW %d.%d rev %d\n", major, minor, rev);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, major);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, minor);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_REVISION, rev);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 8);

    if (!glfwInit())
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char *description)
{
    printf("glfw error callback triggered\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: %s\n", error, description);
}

void glfw_key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void eternity_cleanup(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}

static int parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
    int *arg_count = state->input;

    switch (key)
    {
        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            --(*arg_count);
            break;

        case ARGP_KEY_END:
            if (*arg_count > 0)
                argp_failure(state, 1, 0, "too few arguments");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**eternity.h:**

```
#ifndef ETERNITY_H
#define ETERNITY_H
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <argp.h>

typedef struct eternity_image_data_struct
{
    GLint width, height, bpp;
    uint32_t current_image, next_image;
} eternity_image;

void setup_vbo(GLuint*, GLshort*, GLuint);
void setup_vao(GLuint*);
void glfw_error_callback(int, const char*);
void glfw_key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int);
void eternity_cleanup(GLFWwindow*);
static int parse_opt(int, char*, struct argp_state*);
uint8_t setup_shaders(GLuint*);
uint8_t initialize_glfw(void);
unsigned char* load_image(char*, eternity_image*);
#endif /* ETERNITY_H */
```

**error.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "error.h"

#ifdef __GNUC__
__attribute__ ((format(__printf__, 1, 2)))
#endif
_Noreturn void die(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, vargs);
    va_end(vargs);
    exit(1);
}

void check_error(void)
{
    GLenum error_code;
    const GLubyte *error_string;

    if ((error_code = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        error_string = gluErrorString(error_code);
        DIE("OpenGL Error: %s\n", error_string);
    }
}
```

**error.h:**

```
#ifndef ERROR_H
#define ERROR_H
#define DIE(format, ...) die("%s:%d in %s()\n" format, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__)
void die(const char*, ...);
void check_error(void);
#endif /* ERROR_H */
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  It's often helpful if you can explain how much you have done and what the code is supposed to do.  You call it an image viewer.  Does it support zoom?  How is it run?  Does it process input?  Or just take command arguments?  Perhaps this is obvious in the code, but your main function is long.  Many of us may not be interested in reading the code until we know more about what it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Variable initialisation in condition

Both here:

```
uint8_t rv;
if ((rv = initialize_glfw()))
    DIE("%s%" PRIu8 "\n", "initialize_glfw() failed with code ", rv);
```

here:

```
GLFWwindow *window;
if (!(window = glfwCreateWindow(
                image.width < screen_width ? image.width : screen_width,
                image.height < screen_height ? image.height : screen_height,
                "Eternity",
                NULL,
                NULL)))
{
    glfwTerminate();
    DIE("%s\n", "glfwCreateWindow failed");
}
```

And here:

```
void check_error(void)
{
    GLenum error_code;
    const GLubyte *error_string;

    if ((error_code = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        error_string = gluErrorString(error_code);
        DIE("OpenGL Error: %s\n", error_string);
    }
}
```

Initialising your variables on the condition check should be avoided, it makes the code harder to read, when a simple initialisation on the variable declaration right before the condition check presents a simple and clean solution to what you want to do, making this more readable:

```
GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow(
    image.width < screen_width ? image.width : screen_width,
    image.height < screen_height ? image.height : screen_height,
    "Eternity",
    NULL,
    NULL);

if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    DIE("%s\n", "glfwCreateWindow failed");
}
```

Assigning a value in a condition block may sometimes be the best approach, such as in a while loop, but use it carefully.

---

### Specialisation

Your `main` is too big, you should split your code into smaller functions, each doing it's own thing, not only it makes your code more readable but it also makes your code more maintainable and easier to debug.

---

### Vertices & TexCoords

Both your vertices and texture coordinates can be declared as global constants as they are never changed and a brief description on what they are for could be added for further clarification of their usage and purpose (vertex data for a quad).

---

### OpenGL Vertex Data

Since you're drawing a 2D surface to the screen, you do not need vertices with 3 coordinates, you need only two, thus your vertex data would become:

```
const GLshort vertices[] = {
    -1,  1,
     1,  1,
    -1, -1,
     1, -1,
};
```

Then you need to change your vertex attributes to two values:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_SHORT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

And in your vertex shader, you now have to change attribute `0` to a `vec2`. Here I have changed the variable names, making the code more understandable:

```
#version 440

layout(location = 0) in vec2 in_vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 in_texcoord;

out vec2 texcoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(in_vertex, 0.0, 1.0);
    texcoord = in_texcoord;
}
```

This saves on memory and time, specially if you were to have a lot more vertex data.

---

### Inverted Condition Checks

Some of your conditions checks could be inverted as to make it obvious at a glance what is happening, instead of comparing booleans with a difference operator, make the comparison with an equals check.

So this:

```
if (compile_ok != GL_TRUE)
```

would become

```
if (compile_ok == GL_FALSE)
```

Effectively removing that thought process of "if not true, so if false". Of course in some cases it does make more sense making the inverted comparison, in this case tho it is not justifiable.

---

### Vertex Buffer Object

When calling `setup_vbo`, `GLuint size` is the size of the data in bytes, as it is just passed down to `glBufferData`.

When calling `setup_vbo`, since `vertices` and `texcoords` are declared as an array (and not pointer, this is very important!) and it's data is set right away (telling the compiler the size of these arrays), the size of each of these arrays is just:

```
sizeof(vertices) // for the vertices
sizeof(texcoords) // for the texcoords
```

thus your calls to `setup_vbo` should be:

```
GLuint vertices_vbo = 0;
setup_vbo(&vertices_vbo, vertices, sizeof(vertices));

GLuint texcoords_vbo = 0;
setup_vbo(&texcoords_vbo, texcoords, sizeof(texcoords));
```

Note that this method is recommended to be used with `vertices` and `texcoords` declared as global constants like mentioned before.

Do note that this does not work for arrays passed to a function, even if the parameter is declared as `<type> <name>[]`, arrays passed to functions are always passed as a pointer, thus this:

```
void foo(int arr[])
```

is the same as:

```
void foo(int * arr)
```

thus doing `sizeof(arr)` in both versions of the function `foo` would return the same as `sizeof(int*)`.

---

### Return Type

Some of your functions could use a return type and a rename, functions like:

```
void setup_vbo(GLuint * vbo, GLshort * vbo_array, GLuint size)
void setup_vao(GLuint * vao)
uint8_t setup_shaders(GLuint * shader_program)
```

should become:

```
GLuint create_vbo(GLshort * vbo_array, GLuint size)
GLuint create_vao()
GLuint create_shader_program()
```

You should only return your results through `out` parameters when you are either returning more than one value or the value you are returning is so big you want to avoid a copy (both of which are not a case here).

In the case of `setup_vbo` and `setup_vao` they are only returning an id, so we move it to the return value.

For `setup_shaders` you can return the shader program id through the return value at the same time you can return a error code. `glCreateProgram` returns a non-zero program id, thus when an error occurs you just have to return `0` as it is the only value that is not a valid program id. Then to check for a successful call you can do:

```
GLuint shader_program = create_shader_program();
if (shader_program == GL_FALSE) {
    // failure code here
}
```

---

### Future

For the future, consider separating all your OpenGL code from the rest of the program, and creating specialised functions for texture creation, VBO handling and rendering, this will greatly simplify the addition of new features, such as rendering two images at the same time, or implementing zoom and so on.

Answer (score 6):

**The good**

The code uses library functions such as `argp_parse()` so it's obvious you're not trying to reinvent the wheel. Some of the functions already follow SRP as noted below.

**Reduce function complexity**

The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) is a good thing to keep in mind. This
[website](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=331531.) provides a good list of principles to keep in mind when designing or implementing software.

The functions `setup_vbo()`, `setup_vao()` and `initialize_glfw()` already follow the SRP so you're on the right track here.

Both the `main()` function and the `setup_shaders()` function are too complex and should be broken down into more functions.

The function `setup_shaders()` has two obvious candidate functions it can be broken up into `setup_vs_shader()` and `setup_fs_shader()`. All the code dealing with the vs shader should move to `setup_vs_shader()` and all the code dealing with the fs shader should move to `setup_fs_shader()`. It's possible that the code can be generalized enough so that instead of the two functions I've suggested there can be just `setup_shader()` that takes the necessary parameters to create the proper shader.

The `main()` function in any program should just basically set up the environment for the execution of the code and then execute the code. `main()` should call a function to parse any command line arguments, set a point of return for any error handling, call a function to set up any additional error handling, call a function to execute the body of the program and clean up after execution is terminated. It can return the status of the execution as well. Practically everything after:

```
printf("OpenGL %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

should be in functions called by `main()` rather than in `main()`. This will ease development and any debugging.

**Don't combine variable initializations**

This code is very difficult to read:

```
const GLchar *vs_source =
    "#version 440\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;"
    "layout(location = 1) in vec2 vt;"
    "out vec2 texcoord;"
    "void main() { gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);"
    "texcoord = vt; }",
           *fs_source =
    "#version 440\n"
    "out vec4 frag_color;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "uniform sampler2D texture;"
    "void main() { frag_color = texture2D(texture, texcoord); }";
```

It took me a very long time to find the initialization of `fs_source`.

It would be more readable if the code was:

```
const GLchar *vs_source =
    "#version 440\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;"
    "layout(location = 1) in vec2 vt;"
    "out vec2 texcoord;"
    "void main() { gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);"
    "texcoord = vt; }";
const GLchar *fs_source =
    "#version 440\n"
    "out vec4 frag_color;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "uniform sampler2D texture;"
    "void main() { frag_color = texture2D(texture, texcoord); }";
```

**Magic numbers**

The term "magic numbers" refers to using numeric constants in code that have no explanation of what they are and why they are used. In many cases the numeric constant will be used many times. Named Constants allow you to change the code in only one place when you need to change the number (array usage is an example). Named constants also help make the code more readable.

You can find discussions of Magic Numbers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181921/is-every-number-in-the-code-considered-a-magic-number).

The following code uses numeric constants with no explanation of what they mean:

```
    GLshort vertices[] = {
        -1,  1, 0,
         1,  1, 0,
        -1, -1, 0,
         1, -1, 0
    };

    GLshort texcoords[] = {
         0,  0,
         1,  0,
         0,  1,
         1,  1
    };

    GLuint vertices_vbo = 0;
    setup_vbo(&vertices_vbo, vertices, 12 * sizeof(vertices));

    GLuint texcoords_vbo = 0;
    setup_vbo(&texcoords_vbo, texcoords, 8 * sizeof(texcoords));
```

It would be much better if the code were self documenting by using named constants instead of numeric constants. I would give examples, but I have no clue was 12 or 8 means in this context.